# Fragments, Activities , and Data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an android application where I have an activity with two fragments. One with a map view and the other with a listview. In the main activity I get the user's gps and results from the database based off the gps and send that data to the fragments. That made since instead of calling inside the fragment twice the same data. However, a lot of times the request for the backend data and the gps coordinates of the user are not completed before the fragments are created.

I set up an interface to pass the data back and forth but need to find a way to pause the fragment creation until all data is there.

Any ideas? I can post code if neccesary.

Comment: *to pause the fragment creation until all data is there* ... and pis* off the user with not responding app? ... use calbacks ... or take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't "pause" the fragment.  Have a "loading" state, a "loaded" state, and an "error" state.  Then show the user what is going on between each state.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not block** the fragment UI until the data is ready, but instead you should show the user that the page is **loading** (e.g. with a Progress Bar).

Once the data is **ready**, you should **populate** the fragments with data (through a callback) or show an **error** message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I found a better way to do it. So I was passing data from the activity to fragment via an Interface and in the onAttach method of the fragment. Instead I created a Local Broadcast Manager that listens for the data to be complete in the activity class and sends to the map fragment to populate.

Hope this helps someone else.